# Finding out why Reboot only stops the system

Tags: linux, reboot, puppy-linux

I'm using puppy on a 500 MB ram machine.It works quite fine so far, but whenever I type in reboot........all stops and I need to manually shut down the machine and restart it (energy switch).

I've thought at first that it is just a problem of the machine I'm letting it run on and thus used puppy in a virtualbox to see what I can do there and found out I have the same problem there (on another PC btw).

As I'm unsure there, what can I do there to find out WHY the reboot command does not what it is intended to do?

The command I type in (non sudo):

```
reboot
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what it was.....reboot works fine but as the system starts with "x" used `reboot` does not what it does in a pure console run. Instead one needs to use `wmreboot`, then things work as intended.